# Alternate image position change left and right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a number of elements that are being dynamically added to a page with php. I would like the images to alternate sides (left and right) for each item.

I have tried playing around with nth odd/even but can't seem to get it to work.

Is there something I am missing?

Here is an example of what will get outputted from my php code. I want the first image to be on the left and the second image to be on the right.

```css
.package {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-left {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-img {
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 58.333333%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
}

.col-content {
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  width: 41.666667%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.packages {
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-content h3 {
  color: #6f6ab2;
}

.col-content h5 {
  color: #ccae4c !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="packages">
  <div class="package">
    <!-- card -->
    <div class="card-left">
      <div class="col-img">
        <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-content">
        <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
        <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
          pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>
        <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end card -->
  </div>
  <div class="package">
    <!-- card -->
    <div class="card-left">
      <div class="col-img">
        <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-content">
        <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
        <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
          pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>
        <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end card -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-child` and co always look for elements in the same immediate parent node, so if you used it on `col-img` for example, it wouldn't work since there's only one `col-img` element in one given parent node (`card-left`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `display:flex` in the `.card-left` class and for alternate image position change use `flex-direction: row-reverse` using `:nth-child(even)` selector

```css
.package {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-left {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.package:nth-child(even) .card-left {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.col-img {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 58.333333%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.col-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  width: 41.666667%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.packages {
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-content h3 {
  color: #6f6ab2;
}

.col-content h5 {
  color: #ccae4c !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="package">
  <!-- card -->
  <div class="card-left">
    <div class="col-img">
      <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
      <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
      <p> </p>
      <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
        pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>
      <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="package">
  <div class="card-left">
    <div class="col-img">
      <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
      <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
      <p> </p>
      <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
        pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>
      <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use what you already have and set .package:nth-child(even) .col-img { float: right; }

```css
.package {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.package:nth-child(even) .col-img {
  float: right;
}

.card-left {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-img {
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 58.333333%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
}

.col-content {
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  width: 41.666667%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.packages {
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-content h3 {
  color: #6f6ab2;
}

.col-content h5 {
  color: #ccae4c !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="packages">


  <div class="package">
    <!-- card -->
    <div class="card-left">
      <div class="col-img">
        <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-content">
        <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
        <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
          pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>


        <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end card -->
  </div>










  <div class="package">
    <!-- card -->
    <div class="card-left">
      <div class="col-img">
        <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-content">
        <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
        <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
          pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>


        <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end card -->
  </div>









</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.package {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-left {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-img {
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 58.333333%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.package:nth-child(even) .col-img{
  float: right;
}

.col-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
}

.col-content {
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  width: 41.666667%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.packages {
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-content h3 {
  color: #6f6ab2;
}

.col-content h5 {
  color: #ccae4c !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="packages">


  <div class="package">
    <!-- card -->
    <div class="card-left">
      <div class="col-img">
        <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg">
        </div>
      <div class="col-content">
        <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
        <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
          pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>


        <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end card -->
  </div>










  <div class="package">
    <!-- card -->
    <div class="card-left">
      <div class="col-img">
        <img src="https://www.box.com/sites/default/files/img/social/box1200x630.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-content">
        <h3>Fake Room Package for Testing</h3>
        <h5> This is a custom headline! </h5>
        <p> </p>
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille t-bone tail, shankle meatloaf jowl jerky. Tongue shank cupim, sirloin flank pork chop capicola. Short ribs short loin doner corned beef pastrami. Leberkas beef jowl venison burgdoggen pork chop chuck
          pork belly bresaola turducken ham hock sirloin kevin porchetta rump. Alcatra shank pig tenderloin, cow meatloaf strip steak prosciutto. Ground round meatball fatback shankle strip steak pork chop shank cupim tail beef alcatra beef ribs.</p>


        <p></p> <a class="btn purple" href="#" target="_blank"><span>Check Availability</span></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end card -->
  </div>









</div>
```